# is rbenv possible on a shared dreamhost?

Tags: ruby, dreamhost, rbenv

Since dreamhost has very old default settings i would like to use 1.9.3 and newer Ruby on Rails.

```
[bayhawks]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
[bayhawks]$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3
```

I know there is a [wiki page for RVM](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM).

But i would like to use rbenv, because its more lightweight and and i can change the ruby version on project basis.

Did someone has used rbenv on dreamhost and can share the information if this is working dreamhost or there are some issues against rbenv on dreamhost?

Comment: That page doesn't apply on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work.  The short version is that you have to use ruby-build to build your own version of ruby on your account, but unlike some other shared hosting providers, DreamHost actually allows you to do that.  You can see a more lengthy rundown of the exact step by step details at my blog here:

http://blog.micahchalmer.net/blog/2012/dreamhost-shared-hosting-rbenv